# How to change a Table's Connection in Power Pivot

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerpivot

Is there a way I can change the Connection for a particular table in PowerPivot? All things I've researched talk about changing the Connection object itself. But I have 5 tables that refer to a single connection and I only need to change connection data for one of these tables.

Comment: Did you ever find an way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change a table's connection go to the "Design" ribbon in PowerPivot then select "Existing Connections" then select "PowerPivot Data Connections" which will list all your existing connections. Select the connection you want to modify and click "Edit". You can then chose to reload all the tables from the now changed connection by clicking "Refresh" in the "Existing Connections" window.

Comment: I think what he's after is a way to switch connection on a table without affecting all the other tables that are also using the same connection. i.e change the connection on one of the model tables not all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the table (right click the tab in grid view and select delete).
2. Re-import the table using one of the options in Get External Data, but do not use an existing connection.  For example, if you are pulling from a data base, use the *From Database* drop down.  This will cause a new connection to be created and used.

Inspired by [Paul Te Braak's BI blog](https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/managing-connections-in-power-pivot/), which explains how to add a table to an existing connection by opening the connection and selecting the table or adding a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerPivot -> Design tab, select a table and click Table Properties. In the dialog you can change the name of the table that's being used.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-changes-to-an-existing-data-source-in-power-pivot-9cb508d3-1a83-4d83-a944-700ce41332b6